# Mvvmcross Android Fragment (ShowViewModel) Custom Animation effect (swipe)

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, fragment-transitions

I have a problem with override Custom Animation on my Fragment. I have on my Home view three buttons (First, Second and Third) and when I'm inside this views I want swipe between those view and I need swipe animation effect from left to right and from right to left etc..

**For Example my SecondFragments looks like this:**

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
    public class SecondFragment : BaseFragment<SecondViewModel>, View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        private Easter _easter;
        protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.fragment_second;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            _easter = new Easter(new KonamiCode());

            var easyEgg = new CustomEgg("Easy")
                .WatchForSequence(Command.SwipeLeft(), Command.SwipeRight());

            _easter = new Easter(easyEgg);=
            _easter.CommandDetected += cmd => DoSwipe(cmd.Value);

            var coreLayout = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.coreLayout);
            coreLayout?.SetOnTouchListener(this);

            return view;
        }

        private void DoSwipe(string swipeText)
        {
            if (swipeText.Equals("LEFT"))
            {
                Activity.OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animator.slide_to_right, Resource.Animator.slide_from_left);
            }

            if (swipeText.Equals("RIGHT"))
            {
                Activity.OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animator.slide_to_left, Resource.Animator.slide_from_right);
            }

            ViewModel.SwipeView(swipeText);
        }

        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            _easter.OnTouchEvent(e);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Method ViewModel.SwipeView looks like:**

```
public override void SwipeView(string swipeText)
        {
            if (swipeText.Equals("RIGHT"))
            {
                Close(this);
                UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("RIGHT SWIPE!");
                ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>();
            }

            if (swipeText.Equals("LEFT"))
            {
                Close(this);
                UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("LEFT SWIPE!");
                ShowViewModel<ThirdViewModel>();
            }
        }
```

I tried Activity.OverridePendingTransition for this but it doesnt work. I tried something with TransactionManager but still doesnt work. I need just override animations only for these three view no for whole app.

For example my test project is [HERE](https://github.com/pinkysek/XabluTest/tree/master/XabluAppTest) on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried Activity.OverridePendingTransition for this but it doesnt work.

[OverridePendingTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) allows you to specify a custom animation when starting an activity from outside the `Context` of the current top `Activity`. That means `OverridePendingTransition` method **only be called** immediately after one of the flavors of `startActivity(Intent)` or `finish()` to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next. So when you swipe between those `Fragment`, it has no effect.

> Difference between Animator folder and Anim fodler.

An animation resource can define one of two types of animations: [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Property) and [View Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View).

1. Property Animation

   File Location:

   ```
   Resource/animator/filename.xml
   ```

   SYNTAX:

   The file must have a single root element: either `<set>`, `<objectAnimator>`, or `<valueAnimator>`. You can group animation elements together inside the `<set>` element, including other `<set>` elements.
2. View Animation

   File Location:

   ```
   Resource/anim/filename.xml
   ```

   SYNTAX:

   The file must have a single root element: either an `<alpha>`, `<scale>`, `<translate>`, `<rotate>`, or `<set>` element that holds a group (or groups) of other animation elements (even nested `<set>` elements).

Since your animation use `translate`, I suggest you put these `xml` file in `Resource/anim` folder.

> I need just override animations only for these three view no for whole app.

Since your base `Activity` is `MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivityas`, you can override  `OnBeforeFragmentChanging` method to set a custom transition animation.

```
public override void OnBeforeFragmentChanging(MvvmCross.Droid.Shared.Caching.IMvxCachedFragmentInfo fragmentInfo, Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction transaction)
{
    //Replace this animation with your own animation.
    transaction.SetCustomAnimations(
        // Your entrance animation xml reference
        Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in,
        // Your exit animation xml reference
        Resource.Animation.abc_fade_out,
        Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in,
        Resource.Animation.abc_fade_out);

        base.OnBeforeFragmentChanging(fragmentInfo, transaction);
}
```

`SetCustomAnimations` set specific animation resources to run for the fragments that are entering and exiting in this transaction. The popEnter and popExit animations will be played for enter/exit operations specifically when popping the back stack.

```
FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations (int enter, 
            int exit, 
            int popEnter, 
            int popExit)
```

**EDIT :**

Custom animation for every swipe between `Fragment`, for every `Fragment`, you could custom animation like this :

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
public class SecondFragment : BaseFragment<SecondViewModel>, View.IOnTouchListener
{ 
    private void DoSwipe(string swipeText)
    {
        if (swipeText.Equals("LEFT"))
        {
            FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                .SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_from_left, Resource.Animation.slide_from_right)
                .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame,ThirdFragment.NewInstance(null))
                .Commit();
        }
        if (swipeText.Equals("RIGHT"))
        {
            ...
        }

        ViewModel.SwipeView(swipeText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok.. thanks for the explanation about animations... Yes I tried override OnBeforeFragmentChanging in my base Activity but problem is I need it only for these three views (it will resolve maybe new Activity only for these views right?) but problem is how I can make different animation for left and right swipe?

Comment: @pnk, you mean  different animation for left and right swipe in these three `Viewpager`, or different animation for other `Fragments` in this base `Activity`?

Comment: Ye I mean different animation for left and right swipe.. but I dont have a Viewpage there in my project how You can see (https://github.com/pinkysek/XabluTest/tree/master/XabluAppTest).. I have normal Fragments and change views with normal ShowViewModel...

Comment: Still I don't get it how I can make animaton for example Left Swipe (to_left, from_right) and Right Swipe (to_right, from_left). This OnBeforeFragmentChanging is just for all fragments which use this activity so I dont know here if it Left or Right swipe. I thought if I can make something in my DoSwipe method in fragment where I can know if it Right or Left swipe. I dont know maybe I'm just little confused.

Comment: @pnk, when a new `Fragment` is enter,  its animation is the `enter`, and the  older `Fragment` will exit, its animation is `exit`, is still an yproblem?

Comment: ye but OnBeforeFragmentChanging method in base Activity is for all fragments which used this Activity... I need change animation just for these three views.. ye I can know which view it is for example from fragmentInfo.Tag but I dont know in this method if it is Left or Right swipe.

Comment: @pnk, please look at my EDIT answer, you could custom the animation in your `DoSwipe` method.

Comment: Oh ye sorry... I think it works fine right now  =) Thanks you so much men.

Comment: Btw I have a problem...when I change screen orientation I have a error but its only after Swipe when I change oriantation before Swipe its ok... "Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to find the default constructor on type MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxFragment. Please provide the missing constructor. ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown."

Comment: @pnk, you could add this and try again : `ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation`.

Comment: It works.. but in some views I have specifit layout for Portrait and for Landscape so in OnCreateView I have this code:  _view = this.BindingInflate(orientation == Orientation.Landscape ? FragmentLandscapeId : FragmentId, null); ... but when I added ConfigurationChanges now its not Call this... so I need probably override OnConfigurationChange right? But how I add new layout in this method?

Comment: or if here     `FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                    .SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.slide_from_right, Resource.Animation.slide_to_left)
                    .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, GroupSalesFragment.NewInstance(null))
                    .Commit();` I can make something better for no error...

Comment: @pnk, for a better solution, you could open a new question in stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok new question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295387/after-fragment-newinstance-unable-to-find-the-default-constructor-on-type-mvvmcr

Answer (score 1):

They best way you could achieve this is by using a ViewPager that contains your fragments. I implemented the exact thing yesterday, you can look at [this example](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/XPlatformMenus/XPlatformMenus.Droid/Fragments/Android%20Specific/ExampleViewPagerFragment.cs) on how to use this with MvvmCross.